# dataframe python ... 'list' object has no attribute 'equals'

Tags: python, dataframe

I use Python 3 via Jupyter.

I created a `DataFrame` called `DataSetJuly`. I want to create another DataFrame with all the information in `DataSetJuly`, except I only need all rows with the column variable `"contra_party_type"` equal to `'C'`. Now, it is very easy to write

```
DataSetJuly.loc[DataSetJuly['contra_party_type']=='C']
```

and python doees not complain. I can also get the lenght of that DataFrame, I write:

```
len(DataSetJuly.loc[DataSetJuly['contra_party_type']=='C'])
```

I get the answer 771. So, no problem. But, if I write

```
ATrades = DataSetJuly.loc[DataSetJuly['contra_party_type']=='C']
```

I get an error ... `'list' object has no attribute 'equals'`

DOes anybody know what causes this error and what I am doing wrong ? 
Cheers, Jesper.

DataSetJuly:

```
trd_exctn_dt    trd_exctn_tm    contra_party_type   ascii_rptd_vol_tx   rptd_pr yld_pt  side    sttl_dt msg_seq_nb
0   2018-07-02  9:35:21 D   250000.0    98.623000   4.475237    S   7/5/2018    4418
1   2018-07-02  9:39:08 D   150000.0    98.610000   4.476914    S   7/5/2018    4747


`---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    700                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    701                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 702             printer.pretty(obj)
    703             printer.flush()
    704             return stream.getvalue()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\pretty.py in pretty(self, obj)
    398                         if cls is not object \
    399                                 and callable(cls.__dict__.get('__repr__')):
--> 400                             return _repr_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
    401 
    402             return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\pretty.py in _repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
    693     """A pprint that just redirects to the normal repr function."""
    694     # Find newlines and replace them with p.break_()
--> 695     output = repr(obj)
    696     for idx,output_line in enumerate(output.splitlines()):
    697         if idx:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py in __repr__(self)
     80         Yields Bytestring in Py2, Unicode String in py3.
     81         """
---> 82         return str(self)
     83 
     84 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py in __str__(self)
     59 
     60         if compat.PY3:
---> 61             return self.__unicode__()
     62         return self.__bytes__()
     63 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __unicode__(self)
    661             width = None
    662         self.to_string(buf=buf, max_rows=max_rows, max_cols=max_cols,
--> 663                        line_width=width, show_dimensions=show_dimensions)
    664 
    665         return buf.getvalue()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in to_string(self, buf, columns, col_space, header, index, na_rep, formatters, float_format, sparsify, index_names, justify, line_width, max_rows, max_cols, show_dimensions)
   1965                                            max_rows=max_rows,
   1966                                            max_cols=max_cols,
-> 1967                                            show_dimensions=show_dimensions)
   1968         formatter.to_string()
   1969 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in __init__(self, frame, buf, columns, col_space, header, index, na_rep, formatters, justify, float_format, sparsify, index_names, line_width, max_rows, max_cols, show_dimensions, decimal, table_id, **kwds)
    430             self.columns = frame.columns
    431 
--> 432         self._chk_truncate()
    433         self.adj = _get_adjustment()
    434 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in _chk_truncate(self)
    502                 row_num = max_rows_adj // 2
    503                 frame = concat((frame.iloc[:row_num, :],
--> 504                                 frame.iloc[-row_num:, :]))
    505             self.tr_row_num = row_num
    506 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py in concat(objs, axis, join, join_axes, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
    224                        verify_integrity=verify_integrity,
    225                        copy=copy, sort=sort)
--> 226     return op.get_result()
    227 
    228 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py in get_result(self)
    414 
    415                     obj_labels = mgr.axes[ax]
--> 416                     if not new_labels.equals(obj_labels):
    417                         indexers[ax] = obj_labels.reindex(new_labels)[1]
    418 

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'equals'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
    344             if method is not None:
--> 345                 return method()
    346             return None
    347         else:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _repr_html_(self)
    694 
    695             return self.to_html(max_rows=max_rows, max_cols=max_cols,
--> 696                                 show_dimensions=show_dimensions, notebook=True)
    697         else:
    698             return None

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in to_html(self, buf, columns, col_space, header, index, na_rep, formatters, float_format, sparsify, index_names, justify, bold_rows, classes, escape, max_rows, max_cols, show_dimensions, notebook, decimal, border, table_id)
   2030                                            max_cols=max_cols,
   2031                                            show_dimensions=show_dimensions,
-> 2032                                            decimal=decimal, table_id=table_id)
   2033         # TODO: a generic formatter wld b in DataFrameFormatter
   2034         formatter.to_html(classes=classes, notebook=notebook, border=border)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in __init__(self, frame, buf, columns, col_space, header, index, na_rep, formatters, justify, float_format, sparsify, index_names, line_width, max_rows, max_cols, show_dimensions, decimal, table_id, **kwds)
    430             self.columns = frame.columns
    431 
--> 432         self._chk_truncate()
    433         self.adj = _get_adjustment()
    434 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in _chk_truncate(self)
    502                 row_num = max_rows_adj // 2
    503                 frame = concat((frame.iloc[:row_num, :],
--> 504                                 frame.iloc[-row_num:, :]))
    505             self.tr_row_num = row_num
    506 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py in concat(objs, axis, join, join_axes, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
    224                        verify_integrity=verify_integrity,
    225                        copy=copy, sort=sort)
--> 226     return op.get_result()
    227 
    228 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py in get_result(self)
    414 
    415                     obj_labels = mgr.axes[ax]
--> 416                     if not new_labels.equals(obj_labels):
    417                         indexers[ax] = obj_labels.reindex(new_labels)[1]
    418 

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'equals'`
```

Comment: Is it just that error line, or do you get more traceback? If the latter, could you [edit] it into your question?

Comment: Is `ATrades` a completely new variable, or has it been defined before?

Comment: Yes, ATrades is new

Comment: ... finally the traceback is in the post ...

Comment: Does it work if you take out loc?  ATrades = DataSetJuly[DataSetJuly['contra_party_type']=='C']

Comment: Something else is going on. Firstly, I don't see your actual code that causes this error in the traceback. I'm guessing it actually happens when you type `ATrades` by itself on a line, after the assignment, since the traceback hints at a formatting problem.

Comment: so, now I get the following: 'list' object has no attribute 'is_unique' ... when I run the line DataSetJuly.loc[(DataSetJuly['contra_party_type']=='C')]

Comment: A [mcve] would be very helpful. See if you can trim down your dataframe to the absolute minimum to get the same problem; which may be a data frame of just 1 column and 2 rows. You can fake the data to protect the innocents if needs be.

Comment: @VanTan that may indeed work, since Pandas will do the most logical thing (use a boolean array for row-wise indexing), but I'm curious why the above doesn't work, or causes an error in such a weird way.

Comment: Yes, you are right ... I ran the code and there were no traceback initially .. then when I type in ATrades ... I got the traceback ...

Comment: @terman it is likely your session is just messed up now. You should probably quit and restart, and see if the problem goes away. You have likely assigned something that is a Python built-in to something else earlier, and that is now causing errors.

Comment: What does `ATrades.columns` look like?

Comment: @9769953 ... you are right, but I am very careful to restart and clear the Kernel everytime just to be sure it is not messed up

Comment: @VanTan ... running DataSetJuly[(DataSetJuly['contra_party_type']=='C')] ... will produce the same ... 'list' object has no attribute 'is_unique'

Comment: Well, no-one wants to restart a whole analysis session. But you should go through your session history and try and spot any awkward assignments, such as, for example, `list = numpy.array`.

Comment: @9769953 ... I will do that ... thanks for having a look !

Comment: please show us what the dataframe looks like

Comment: @VanTan ... I included some of the dataframe as it is quite a big dataset ... the columns is a subset of the original

Comment: I am really surprised that assigning output to a variable throws an error. So either you changed something between checking and assigning, or - more likely - as @9769953 mentioned - something else has gone wrong. You tried restarting the kernal, right?

Comment: @VanTan: from another comment from the OP, and from the traceback, it looks more like that the (pretty) displaying of the new dataframe is the issue. How, is of course still a mystery.